# How to Concatenate user name and surname while adding users from csv?

Tags: powershell, user-accounts, active-directory

I want to add users to AD using the following command in Powershell:
(This is a single line command but I am breaking apart it to be more readable)

```
import-csv C:\list.csv | 

Foreach-Object {

    New-ADUser -Name ([string]::Concat($_.Name , " " , $_.Surname))  
               -GivenName $_.Name  
               -Surname $_.Surname  
               -UserPrincipalName $_.IDNumber  
               -SamAccountName $_.IDNumber  
               -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $_.IDNumber -AsPlainText -force)  
               -Description $_.UnitName  
               -DisplayName ([string]::Concat("'", $_.Name , " " , $_.Surname, "'"))  
               -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true  
               -Enabled $True 
               -Path ([string]::Concat("OU=" , $_.Group , ",DC=mydomain,DC=local"))
}
```

When I run the command I get a "bad syntax" error.

> New-ADUser : The object name has bad syntax 
>   At C:\addUsers.ps1:6 char:5
>   +     New-ADUser -Name ([string]::Concat($*.Name , " " , $*.Surname))  -GivenName $_.A ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=JOHN WAYNE,OU=,DC=mydomain,DC=local:String) [New-ADUser], ADException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8335, Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADUser

Since I am new to Active Directory and Powershell I thought it is best to ask here for a guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
-Name $($_.Name + " " + $_.Surname)
```

I don't have the cmdlet to test it with, but this should concatenate the first and last name with a space between.

[image]

Comment: I accept this as an answer in order community to be informed, eventhough I did something else.